# Why can't everyone see down votes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes, privileges, score

I recently discovered that I now have the power to see how many up and down votes a given question or answer has, rather than just the sum.  I find it strange that this information is not available to everyone, as it could be helpful for making personal decisions about e.g. which answers are most useful or authoritative.

> Suggestion: Could we make this feature available to everyone?

Comment: there are quite some posts on meta.stackexchange. [This one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286897/show-the-vote-split-by-default) is a relatively recent one.

Comment: @JohnMa I'm not proposing what was suggested in the linked post (showing up and down votes by default).  I just don't see why all users should not be able to click the total score to see the breakdown.  This is useful information for everyone, not just the high ranking users.

Comment: I am just posting a recent one. If you search the tag [vote-count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vote-count?sort=newest&pageSize=15), you will see more and the reason why it is declined. But many of those questions are old (in 2009, 2010). I am not sure if the technical problem still persists.

Comment: This feature request on Meta Stack Exchange seems similar to yours: [Please reduce or eliminate the reputation required to see the upvote/downvote vote split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72743).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, that's consistent with what I'm proposing.  Judging from the response to that question, many people feel the same as me.    It's a 7 year old post though, and the status quo hasn't changed in that time.  Perhaps a reconsideration of the arguments is in line?

Comment: From what I could gather from the links (particularly the last one by Martin, and its offsprings), the decision to lock this behind reputation does not seem to have been very well thought ([this post seems to show the thought-process behind it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37127/302100]) ). And the arguments against changing this are... weird at best.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo [Another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-is-it-a-privilege-to-view-vote-counts/69854#69854) claims that *it's "expensive" to view the vote count.* I am not knowledgeable enough to know whether this claim is valid or not. (But if true, it is definitely better reason than just: "We just thought it would be fun.")

Comment: You have over 5000 reputation already and you just know this feature? (You should know this when you get just over 1000)

Comment: One reason could be to be able to give  meaningful power privileges to high rep users, i guess.

Comment: Related older post (so far no answers): [Why can only established users view vote counts?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9659)

Comment: [They can with some effort](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep/).

Comment: @TrầnThúcMinhTrí: I have over 50k reputation, and discovered I have this power...by reading this question. :) Then again, I've also never cared how many people vote in either direction -- I figure it's my *opinion* that I can offer, rather than my ability to follow the herd.

Comment: It is available to everyone, just get this chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-vote-totals-without/oibfliilcglieepgkdkahpfiiigdijdd?hl=en