# What is the point of restricting people from seeing upvote/downvote ratios?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, voting, privileges

I notice that on many StackExchanges, you can't see how many upvotes or downvotes a post got, only the net total. I needed to get to $1000$ rep on MSE to be able to view the upvote and downvote counts. However, the only use I can imagine for this feature is out of curiosity. Like if you saw a post with a score of $1$, it would be pretty cool to see that it was actually a controversial post with $11$ upvotes and $10$ downvotes. So, what is the point of restricting this feature to such a high-rep even though it is just a neat little feature? It's not like people can abuse this power like how people can spam comments or questions or do bad moderation. It only affects the knowledge of the reader, and it can also be helpful to the community as well by letting people know that a post with score $5$ isn't that reliable since it actually had $44$ upvotes and $39$ downvotes. I notice that other sites like YouTube and Reddit don't let you see the quantities of upvotes and downvotes separately, either, so maybe it is an industry issue?

EDIT: I found this example [What exactly is a "Rep-farmer", and what can we/the moderators do about them?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28951/what-exactly-is-a-rep-farmer-and-what-can-we-the-moderators-do-about-them), check the answer with $-1$ score, it actually has $10$ upvotes and $11$ downvotes, which shows that their take is actually worthy of deeper thought instead of a take that can be easily dismissed as stupid.

Comment: Older posts on this meta which seems related (perhaps even duplicates): [Why can only established users view vote counts?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9659) and [Why can't everyone see down votes?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28186)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I guess this is  some motivation for users to increase their rep........

Comment: Some people love to complain. And the rest of us get our web site filled with their complaints and the mods have to spend their time dealing with their complaints. Giving the drive-by complainers one less thing  to complain about seems reason enough to me.

Comment: I think of this as a privilege that comes with earning reputation.  Congratulations on reaching 1,000 points.