# Displaying total number of up-votes and down-votes together

Tags: discussion, support, voting

I observed a nice feature in the MSE and here in meta site too.

If we click on the place where votes are shown we can see the total number of upvotes and downvotes together. Like this [image]

But I did not find the same feature in MathOverflow, StackOverflow, or in meta StackExchange. Is this feature unique to MSE?

Comment: As suggested, this is a privilege you earned when you reach 1k reps. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user)

Comment: A related feature request on this meta: [Why can only established users view vote counts?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9659) And on [meta.se]: [Please reduce or eliminate the reputation required to see the upvote/downvote vote split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72743).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not unique. You need to have at least 1000 points to have the privilege of accessing this feature.

Your score on the aforementioned sites is simply too low.